# Creating a custom defect trend chart using App SDK 2.0

Tags: rally

I've been tasked with plotting some defect charts using Rally historical data. Right now I'm using a simple REST client to pull data at certain points in time and plot the count on a spreadsheet. What I'm doing right now is:

```
{
find : {
    "_ProjectHierarchy": <projectId>, 
    "_TypeHierarchy": -51006, 
    "FoundInBuild" : {$regex: "3\\.3\\."},
    "State" : {$in : ["Submitted","Open"] },
    $or: [ 
       {"Severity" : { $in : ["Catastrophic","Severe"] }},
       {"Priority" : "showstopper"}
    ],
    "__At" : "<date>"
},

pagesize : 1,false
}
```

I just run this once for every date I need the data for. That's a *lot* of queries! What I'm looking for is a way to run a single query using _ValidFrom and _ValidTo to enclose a time range, then pass it on to a SnapshotStore, then plot that on a Chart? I'm certain there's a way to do it, but I can't figure it out from the docs. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the example space for AppSDK2 and Lookback API is presently a bit thin. There are some cool apps out there, for instance, you may wish to check out David Thomas' cool Hackathon app:

[Defect Re-work Trend](https://github.com/RallyHackathon/DefectRework)

As a starting point. It queries LBAPI for Defects and stores the resulting data in a SnapshotStore. The App itself measures Defect "thrash" or the trending around how many times a Defect is re-opened during a particular development cycle.

In reviewing Hackathon apps, just be aware that certain methods and syntax for the SnapshotStore may change slightly in a future release of AppSDK2.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. From what I can tell I need to come up with my own map/reduce on the datastore, populate a custom Store and feed that to a Chart. Am I correct in looking at the aggregate() and each() methods? Or should I try to use collect("_UnformattedID") instead and filter the store on _ValidFrom and _ValidTo day by day?

Comment: Hi Peter, yes you're correct that you'll need to supply your own map/reduction on the snapshots, for now. There is an available JS time-series library that is separate from AppSDK2 called lumenize, that provides some great assistance for processing the time series data, however, lumenize has some bugs and will be changing before AppSDK2.0p6 to make it more convenient to use. You can see how David did his reduction within this chunk of the Defect Rework app: https://github.com/RallyHackathon/DefectRework/blob/master/src/DefectReworkTable/App.js .